# How to access nested property at script_fields on elastic 5.x

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to iterate over nested objects on painless script_fields for my query but notation doc['nestedProperty.property'] does not gave me the value, neither does using array notation doc['nestedProperty.property'][0]

Any idea on how to use this?

## EDIT

A document example:

```
{
    "neestedProperty": [
      {
        "property": 12,
        "innerNeestedProperty": {
          "innerProperty1": 45,
          "innerProperty2": -45
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

example query:

```
{
  "query": {
    match_all: {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "scripted": {
      "script": {
        "inline": "doc['neestedProperty.property'] * params.multiplier",
        "params": {
          "multiplier": 100
        },
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show your script field definition if possible and a sample document.

Comment: @Val examples have been added, thanks

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 9):

The `doc`-notation apparently doesn't work on nested objects, but you could directly access the `_source`-object as Horst Seirer pointed out.

Complication is that accessing `_source` depends on the context where your script is executed; the `ctx`-variable is not always available.
For `scripted_fields`, you can instead use `params._source`. But that won't be available on other contexts (e.g. in the query-part)

After you have the `_source`, accessing elements can be done with `get`, or using dot-notation, and the nested fields will be an array. So for example `params._source.nestedProperty[0].property` will get the value from the first nested object.

For scripted fields, you should return one object, but that can be an array. So in your example, I'd use something like this:

```
def returnval=[];
for (nested in params._source.nestedProperty) {
  returnval.add(nested['property']*params.multiplier)
}
return returnval;
```

Even though you're calling the source as a parameter, you don't have to add it in your parameter list.

### Edit

The above is useful if you need to script from the point of view of your parent document (maybe you need to combine several nested documents).

There is however, a disadvantage in that you can only use the raw source, which means non-analyzed strings, and dates that are just strings, etc.

So often it may be a lot easier to just use the scripted fields on your nested documents directly, by including `script_fields` in an `inner_hits` section. Like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "nestedProperty",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "_source": true, 
        "script_fields": {
          "my_value": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['nestedProperty.property'].value*params.multiplier",
              "params": {
                "multiplier": 100
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What this code does is just looking at each of the nested documents individually (as they are internally stored as seperate documents), and run a script on them. And these (internally stored seperate) documents *can* use the doc-notation.

The result will give you your original documents, along with a section `inner_hits` that contains each of the nested documents with their source, and a scripted field `my_value`.

It may only feel weird that you are using the nested document as a seperate entry, yet still have to use the full path (`nestedProperty.property`)

And you have to mind the fact that this query as it is now only returns documents that *have* nested documents in them, whereas the code before would return the document with as scripted field an empty array. However, if you want all documents you can use a bool-query with a `match_all`-clause.

Finally, I don't know if this works on elastic 5 (as was the original question), but I've confirmed on 7.3, and according to the docs it should also work on e.g. 5.0.

And I know I'm late, but maybe I can help others looking for the same answer.

Comment: It works, but I can't call `.value` on this property. In my scripted field I substract two dates, so I need two dates. Returned value from params is string instead of date and I can't call:
`params._source.created_at.value.millis`. Any solution?

Comment: @barmic I've updated my answer, does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks @EmilBode I was using _source include on top hits which was showing me whole list of fields, but your answer was savior. Was searching for this from 10 hours.

Comment: @EmilBode, is it possible to search string through params._source.field.contains('sample word')?

Comment: @sagarpavan Sure it's possible, though you need to write it a little differently. The thing to understand is that once you have the source, it's just writing painless, which is just Java-without-some-functionality.
So you need to iterate over arrays yourself, and provide some fallback for values that aren't present.

Answer (score 2):

ACTUALLY, I found the solution on discuss.elastic.co [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-use-nested-properties-fields-in-query-script/214621)...

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "new_scripted_field_name": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['nestedProperty.property'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Contrary to @Emil Bode's answer, you can use `doc`, just that you **must** use dot notation rather than bracket notation.

I am using Elasticsearch v7 and the discuss.elastic.co post uses Elasticsearch v6.

Comment: Are you sure? It doesn't work here with me on 7.14. Or are you just having a field with a subfield?

If I have a nested property, it tells me `A document doesn't have a value for a field! ...`

Comment: And note that in the link you provide, the question asker doesn't have a nested field.

Answer (score -1):

The *_source* object is in fact a *LinkedHashMap* (see the chapter about Painless Debugging in the reference documentation.) So in order to access a field you can use the *get* method. This is handy if you need to select document fields dynamic by parameter.

The other way to select a field is to use the dot syntax:

```
ctx._source.some_field
```

When navigating and selecting document fields you have to keep in mind what data type a field has.

For your specific case the *neestedProperty* field is a list (/*ArrayList*) of a nested type which you can iterate. The elements of this list will be of type *LinkedHashMap*.

So for your example this would be:

```
ArrayList nestedObjects = ctx._source.get('neestedProperty'); 

for(o IN nestedObjects) { 
    o.get('property') = o.get('property')*params.multiplier; 
}
```